# jquery.validate load new page on success from JSOn

Tags: jquery

Have a function that is being called after the form submit is processed. I am using JQuery 1.8 and jquery.validate.

I have the following function that does the check and processes the call to the server and receives a JSON success call back:

```
<input type="submit" value="Continue" 
                      name="submit_first" onclick="verifyPge();" />
```

This is the function that I need to add the load page to and it needs to load in the same window (JQuery load page)
This function runs through the UI checks using jquery.validate and I need to add a new function to this verifyPge(); function so that the form loads a new page. Using the method or action is not an option and the validate is being called on the form ID to keep it seperate.
// JavaScript Document
 $().ready(function() {

```
// validate signup form on keyup and submit
$("#yourInfo").validate({

    rules: {
        month: {
            required: true,
        },
        day: {
            required: true,
        },
        year: {
            required: true
        },

    },
    messages: {
        month: {
            required: "Please select the month you were born",
        },
        day: {
            required: "Please select the day you were born",
        },
        year: {
            required: "Please select the year you were born",
        },
        errorElement: "div"
    }
});
```

});

Any ideas? Basically, after the UI validations are done and the form is processed, I want to load the new page but do it using JQuery Page load and have Jquery switch the page via Ajax.

Comment: you are missing the content from `verifyPge`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure to return the URL in your server

```
// document DOM ready
$(function() {

// validate signup form on keyup and submit
$("#yourInfo").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form){
    // submit the form via ajax
    $.post(
      // your script
      'script.php',
      // your form in a serialized way your server can understand
      form.serializeArray()[0], 
      // success function
      function(url){
        window.location.assign(url); // load the new URL
      }
    );
    return false;
  },
  rules: {
    month: {
        required: true,
    },
    day: {
        required: true,
    },
    year: {
        required: true
    },
  },
  messages: {
    month: {
        required: "Please select the month you were born",
    },
    day: {
        required: "Please select the day you were born",
    },
    year: {
        required: "Please select the year you were born",
    },
    errorElement: "div"
  }
});

});
```

jQuery validate plugin already deal with your form submit, no need to add that `verifyPage()` in the submit button. Using `submitHandler` is the proper way to submit after the form has been validated.

Comment: I'll have to check that with worklight adapter to see if I can put the function in where you have the // your script 'script.php' the validate is only for the UI fields, the verifyPge() is to actually invoke the adapter call. Have to bind the submit button so that jquery.validate does it's job, then send the serialized data through the adapter to the backend... then on success, go to the next page. But I like where the script is going. I'll give it a shot tomorrow and let you know. Thanks.